# Reverse DNS is not working

Tags: ubuntu, bind, reverse-dns

I got a mail server that can't send outbound because I don't have my reverse dns entries correct. Admittedly at first I knew it wasn't configured properly but from every single example I could find on the web as well as some helpful hints around here, it's still not working.

```
$TTL    604800
$ORIGIN 107.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa.
@   IN  SOA ns2.XX.net. root.XX.net. (
              8     ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; Name servers
    IN  NS  ns2.XX.net.             
    IN  NS  ns3.XX.net.
; PTR records
20      IN  PTR     mail.XX.net.
20      IN  PTR     ns2.XX.net.
29      IN  PTR     ns3.XX.net.
```

I can do a dig mail.XX.net and find a forward zone for mail.yup.net but when I try to do a reverse check, dig -x mail.XX.net, I get the following:

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 52342
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;net.XX.mail.in-addr.arpa.        IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
in-addr.arpa.           1725    IN      SOA     b.in-addr-servers.arpa.     nstld.iana.org. (bunch of other numbers)
```

My named.conf.options file:

```
options {
directory "/var/cache/bind";

// If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
// to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
// ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

// If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
// nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
// Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
// the all-0's placeholder.

// forwarders {
//  0.0.0.0;
// };

//========================================================================
// If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
// you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
//========================================================================

recursion no;                 # enables resursive queries
allow-transfer  { none; };      # disable zone transfers by default
allow-query     { any; };
dnssec-validation auto;
auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
};

logging {
  channel zone_xfer {
  file "/etc/bind/xfer.log";
  print-time yes;
  print-category yes;
};
channel namedsyslogging {
  file "/etc/bind/named.syslog";
  print-time yes;
  severity dynamic;
};

category default { namedsyslogging; default_debug; };
category xfer-in { zone_xfer; };
category xfer-out { zone_xfer; };
};
```

This is a part of my named.conf.local file:

```
    zone "107.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa" { type master; notify no; file  "/etc/bind/db.107"; };
```

This should be working but I can't guess what I'm missing or what needs to be tweaked. both mail and ns2 have valid forward zone entries so respectively they have reverse entries as shown, but something isn't right. I understand the NXDOMAIN response means it can't find a valid dns entry. I'm not sure if perhaps top level dns needs more time to update or if this is broken somewhere. Any ideas would be grateful?

Comment: Please update the command output in your question based on using a `dig -x 1.2.3.4` syntax. (i.e. following Iain's suggestion) We also need the actual error message displayed from the SMTP server rejecting the messages, and to ensure our troubleshooting is accurate we will also need the IP address of your mail server. (the one getting refused)

Answer (score 2):

It is normal to supply an IP address to `dig -x` not the name of the host.

Note also that if you are using public IP addresses the ISP has to delegate authority to you to manage the PTRs yourself. Many won't do this so you have to either ask them or use whatever facilities they provide.

```
dig +short google.com
216.58.210.14

dig +short -x  216.58.210.14
lhr08s06-in-f14.1e100.net.
lhr08s06-in-f14.1e100.net.
```

Whereas

```
dig +short google.com
```

returns nothing. In more detail

```
dig -x google.com
<<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.37.rc1.el6_7.4 <<>> -x google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 21504
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;com.google.in-addr.arpa.       IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
in-addr.arpa.           600     IN      SOA     b.in-addr-servers.arpa. nstld.iana.org. 2015072376 1800 900 604800 3600
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using colocated hardware, namecheap for my domain registrar, and it's my DNS server. Basically I'm my own service provider. In either case with the dig -x, I get the same response.

Comment: The problem as stated is that you are using a name rather than an IP in dig -x. Other problems may exist but they are being masked by the first.

Comment: Still the same issue as I stated before I know it's somewhere else, just not sure what I'm missing or where.

Comment: To go further we need the actual name of the domain.

Comment: That would be "interfun.net"

Comment: Still no help? Anyone? Not sure what in my reverse DNS zone file isn't working properly or in my config file isn't causing this to work.

Comment: @MZA: Perhaps if you edited your question to provide the information asked for in the comment to your question, you'd get more help.

Comment: Thanks, I'm too new to know better but I got it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The zone isn't delegated to your nameservers, so they never get a chance to answer:

```
$ dig mail.interfun.net

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9-Debian <<>> mail.interfun.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 64399
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mail.interfun.net.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.interfun.net.      86400   IN      A       162.208.107.20

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
interfun.net.           86400   IN      NS      ns2.interfun.net.
interfun.net.           86400   IN      NS      ns3.interfun.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.interfun.net.       86396   IN      A       162.208.107.20
ns3.interfun.net.       86396   IN      A       216.65.23.102

;; Query time: 232 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 30 11:46:25 AEDT 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 130

$ dig -x 162.208.107.20 +trace @c.root-servers.net

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9-Debian <<>> -x 162.208.107.20 +trace @c.root-servers.net
;; global options: +cmd
.                       518400  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       518400  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20151209170000 20151129160000 62530 . FyXo33h4UlH0HUTz6eMaXpgCsK1C97IW5J9usZUJFVAhnKYUkCmw2dcH FHNqoszd30Wvcb9QlI34JF29pSUWfmmbFV/EGxieMH8AbzvmO3fnDU0E rOWUaxAEqqhntXPRPMb40HABLxAVYI7XPACST4xB+mcOMlq73k/3Mecc LOY=
;; Received 913 bytes from 192.33.4.12#53(c.root-servers.net) in 4244 ms

in-addr.arpa.           172800  IN      NS      a.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.           172800  IN      NS      c.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.           172800  IN      NS      d.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.           172800  IN      NS      f.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.           172800  IN      NS      e.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.           172800  IN      NS      b.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa.           86400   IN      DS      47054 8 2 5CAFCCEC201D1933B4C9F6A9C8F51E51F3B39979058AC21B8DF1B1F2 81CBC6F2
in-addr.arpa.           86400   IN      DS      53696 8 2 13E5501C56B20394DA921B51412D48B7089C5EB6957A7C58553C4D4D 424F04DF
in-addr.arpa.           86400   IN      DS      63982 8 2 AAF4FB5D213EF25AE44679032EBE3514C487D7ABD99D7F5FEC3383D0 30733C73
in-addr.arpa.           86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 2 86400 20151209190000 20151129180000 20499 arpa. aeLbrgv0t06KWmvp0/G1EZN+IJeigUg/TZ1xomRuGPA7YQXuk+UHi5FI v0rl4IBG4Gse2gDl/za0m7cWYrLZCdGpES4Eog/MynmrDbObVV5a0QiR cuqgeDKqKO3R8s22K3p0ffzIZrAr6dpLspvL0cY8idFjA/fPJNp2sklQ Qno=
;; Received 740 bytes from 192.33.4.12#53(c.root-servers.net) in 4633 ms

162.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      NS      r.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      NS      z.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      NS      u.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      NS      v.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      NS      w.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      NS      x.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      NS      y.arin.net.
162.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      DS      948 5 1 31F3282CE72528E8AEEAA2A17ED952D64F4D5302
162.in-addr.arpa.       86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 3 86400 20151208174346 20151117085956 51619 in-addr.arpa. mUsIj7udvyQXhd3Wp8BPPXFOwO4m/AJQWbEDPuKmmdKEbRwerrfMSpLp S7eiJujhRtMrhcVx7c05BWbRwipWeYAh08OzBYagnqJnRhj8udysDPQ7 FjZnDhBYRixnbADKyMh73xNR/15BLzJ2XYMBVBN4wJ2ilxexuF3wHzNN +9CYtiE=
;; Received 387 bytes from 2001:dd8:6::101#53(e.in-addr-servers.arpa) in 620 ms

162.in-addr.arpa.       10800   IN      SOA     z.arin.net. dns-ops.arin.net. 2015111583 1800 900 691200 10800
162.in-addr.arpa.       10800   IN      RRSIG   SOA 5 3 86400 20151213213033 20151129203033 51360 162.in-addr.arpa. APvbV47Tz3NGyUyzIuxwIwH2JBi7PD3DirWOiCOtLbairYcjctHcGq5Q fLrIw8eR059ajHokb6NDT31bCyS1a9FaNZQlK4RX6UiSAF3/XeZ+DXAI TsywoPhTTQkJUq5Hf9QDUa6MNWq+snlmDaqOD7myzxPXO51DfuwwHQgr l9c=
104.208.162.in-addr.arpa. 10800 IN      NSEC    108.208.162.in-addr.arpa. NS RRSIG NSEC
104.208.162.in-addr.arpa. 10800 IN      RRSIG   NSEC 5 5 10800 20151213213033 20151129203033 51360 162.in-addr.arpa. oMslNPJPhxyLqOCb1l1VjBHBY/fuG8R1JGYTCZjCZfUU4icl8g/7gHib xBAqjXR800cz5+hacM5O6RTELXoSZE9wx7p6jN7IoLsBVAvr/DJvipo+ +TBq0Z1FiKLvQkmVm2i1aq0kxqFMYB6faqA1fvjMqxdF2YnOOnNFnINc ioQ=
207.162.in-addr.arpa.   10800   IN      NSEC    0.208.162.in-addr.arpa. NS RRSIG NSEC
207.162.in-addr.arpa.   10800   IN      RRSIG   NSEC 5 4 10800 20151213213033 20151129203033 51360 162.in-addr.arpa. ZsjJ6BAC4gPZYF7Y5jatgfKHP///Q5Keg7HzkTN+Ik6EUpfGIxu64MEt y+pogoTUBXjo4NHZ2Z05alZheqy3xSk6X0rBqks0CUL7ca41oJJJKu0V Dpgpvql3KebPVlUvkkALeY74NxoyiAlPg1frEusSuzM5MeCoTV6+JAlH i40=
;; Received 736 bytes from 72.52.71.2#53(w.arin.net) in 240 ms
```

Thus, the bind config and all the rest of your question isn't relevant.

Comment: My whois says the /22 is directly allocated to "Smith & Hammaker", whoever they are.

Answer (score 0):

The answer came in the form of contacting my IP address provider, the owner of my datacenter. I was able to get a PTR record configured on their end for my mail server and that fixed it all.

I was not aware that being the authoritative DNS server for my network is different from the authoritative DNS server for my ISP in general. I got a PTR record added there and the rest was a quick fix.